# How to create connection pool with mysql database which is present on remote server?

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection-pooling, mysql-connector

i am working on a MVC project in java. For my operation I use database many times. many times my database connection gives my error like connection is not free to use. So I want to create a **connection pool** with my mysql database which is present on a remote server. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use apache commons dbcp: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: Thank you, but I want a example

Answer (score 0):

I would use apache commons dbcp: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Assuming you have a `Properties` object with all the JDBC parameters, you can create a connection pool with:

```
private static DataSource createDataSource(Properties props)
        throws Exception {
    return BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(props);
}
```

If you want to emulate the behavious of an appserver, you can put this datasource in a JNDI container; otherwise, you can just assign it to a static variable.

Now, when whenever you need a JDBC connection, you do:

```
try (Connection cnt = myDataSource.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = cnt.prepareStatement("...")) {
    // lots of very useful things
}
```